# Finding Argmax in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I have a Gaussian random variable $z$, whose mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ are functions of two variables $x$ and $y$. Is there any way in MATLAB so that I can find the values of $x$ and $y$ for which $P(z)$ = $N(z$;$\mu$$(x,y)$,$\sigma$$(x,y))$ is maximised for a given value of $z$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your writing. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Please have a look.

Comment: $P(z)$ is always maximum for $z=\mu$. You need to find $x,y$ such that $\mu(x,y)=z$.

Comment: As @MBaz says, $P(z)$ will be maximized when $z = \mu(x,y),$ unless there are constraints on the values of $x$ and $y$ or on the function $\mu$ that mean $z = \mu(x,y)$ is impossible. Are there any other things about the problem that you're not telling us?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[argvalue, argmin] = min(x);
[argvalue, argmax] = max(x);
```

Also, have a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/matlab-argmax-and-argmin).

Answer (score 0):

If you can express $\mu$ in an functional form, you could use [`fsolve`.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)